# Why does trying to style a Ruby on Rails link_to tag with Tailwindcss not work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, tailwind-css

so I am trying to style a Rails `link_to` tag with tailwind css classes, however they don't all seem to work. Some tailwind classes work but some don't, for example I am trying to do this...

`<%= link_to 'register', new_user_session_path, class: 'text-white text-bold text-md rounded-md border-2 border-white px-8 py-2 h-8' %>`

The first couple classes, `text-white` and `text-bold` don't seem to work while the rest do. I do see that rails generates `<a>` tags in the html for the `link_to` tag like so..

`<a class="text-white text-bold text-md rounded-md border-2 border-white px-8 py-2 h-8" href="/users/sign_in">register</a>`

and the [Tailwind css docs](https://tailwindcss.com/docs) examples use `<button>` tags so I thought that could be an issue but wasn't able to figure that out.

Anyone know how to make the Rails `link_to` tag and Tailwind css play nice together?

Comment: Look at the `<a>` in your browser's "inspect element" tool, that will let you see how the various CSS classes end up being used and where the final colors come from. You could also use `button_to` instead of `link_to` if you really want a `<button>`.

Comment: Isn't `button_to` for submitting a form / params to a url? I am just trying to create a button in a nav bar. I also did try looking int he inspector and can't see the styles, I can add `color: white` to the element, and also just `style: 'color: white'` to the link_to but I would like to do it with pure tailwind if possible

Comment: [`button_to`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to) creates a `<button>` element that can issue a GET request if you specify `method: :get`. You should be able to see the CSS information in the element inspector, usually it is in a panel on the right side of the inspector.

Comment: I think it comes from the way elements are rendered. I experience the same issue with the image_tag and other elements.
My assumption is that dynamic content is messing up with the rendering engine and eventually the style is not applies.